# Why do I have row names?

Tags: r

Hi I am very beginner of R. This function takes a data frame and returns a data frame with two columns each having "The name of each column" and "the number of non-positive entries of that column".

```
CountNonpositives <- function(D)
{

   numericD <- D[sapply(D,is.numeric)] 
   Column_Names <- colnames(numericD)
   Number_of_NonPositive_Values <- apply(numericD, 2 , function(x) length(x[x<=0]))
   output <- data.frame(Column_Names,Number_of_NonPositive_Values)
   return(output)

}
```

The output for Chile dataframe in car library is this:

```
           Column_Names Number_of_NonPositive_Values
population   population                            0
age                 age                            1
income           income                           98
statusquo     statusquo                         1375
```

However, I can't understand why I have the first column names. I want the regular numbers instead.

Can you show me a way?

Answer (score 4):

Change this line:

```
output <- data.frame(Column_Names,Number_of_NonPositive_Values, row.names=NULL)
```

to include the `row.names=NULL` part.

Comment: Ben's approach works but I prefer this one as it stops the problem where it starts. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can set `rownames`:

```
rownames(dat) <- seq_len(nrow(dat))
```

Comment: I got the idea for that. Thanks, it also works great.