# R Function - Count Non Positives

Tags: r

I'm a beginner for R. Please help me with the coding of function as below. Thanks!

Create a function named CountNonpositives that takes a numeric dataframe as its only input parameter.  This function should return a dataframe with one row for each column of the input dataframe.  This output dataframe should have two columns, one giving the name of each column of the input dataframe and the other giving the number of observations of that variable which are not positive.

Note: missing values, if any, must be included in the nonpositive count.

Comment: this reeks of homework.

Comment: @AndyClifton, [what makes you say that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20166649/1270695)?

Comment: You could have done this easily by using subset.

Answer (score 0):

The `sapply` is doing the trick for you. I trust, you can encapsulate it into a function of your specifics.

```
d <- data.frame(
  x = c(sample(-10:10, 10, replace = TRUE),NA),
  y = c(sample(-10:10, 10, replace = TRUE),NA),
  z = c(sample(-10:10, 10, replace = TRUE),NA)
  )

sapply(d, function(x) sum(x<0 & !is.na(x)) )
```

Preview -

```
   > d
         x  y  z
    1    5 10  2
    2    9 -2 -2
    3   -9 10 -2
    4   -1  0  0
    5    2 -9  7
    6   -5  7 -3
    7    1 -7 10
    8  -10  5 -8
    9    8  6 -9
    10  -8 10 -4
    11  NA NA NA
    > sapply(d, function(x) sum(x<0 & !is.na(x)) )
    x y z 
    5 3 6
```

Comment: Thanks, I left that part to the OP with the hope that he/she would manage but wth...